# The web page becomes unresponsive after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

Here I am trying to update my `chart.js` chart using flask based on some user inputs. Since I have multiple charts on one page, I am trying to use ajax to update only a part of my HTML page.

But after the ajax call, the webpage is not responding at all.
I am new to AJAX and Javascript, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my original HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post">
             <select id="select-year-popularity" name="select-year-popularity">
                 <option selected>Year</option>
                 <option value="2017">2017</option>
                 <option value="2018">2018</option>
             </select>
             <select id="select-category" name="select-category">
                 <option>Category</option>
                 <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                 <option value="baby">Baby</option>
             </select>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2" id="but2">Confirm</button>
        </form>
        <h5>Product Category Trend</h5>
        <div id="cate-trend">
        <canvas id="product-popularity-trend"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$("#but2").on("click", function(e){
        console.log("hit here")
           var year =  $("#select-year-popularity").val();
           var cate = $("#select-category").val();
           $.ajax({
                url: "/update_cate_trend",
                type: "POST",
                data:{year:year, cate:cate},
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#cate-tend").replaceWith(response);
                }
           });
           e.preventDefault();
        });
```

And here is my Flask code:

```
@app.route("/update_cate_trend", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def update_trend():
    year = request.form.get("year")
    cate = request.form.get("cate")
    print(year)
    print(cate)
    df_pop_cate = get_cate_popularity(year, cate)
    months_cate_trend = df_pop_cate.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
    sales_cate_trend = df_pop_cate.iloc[:, 1].tolist()
    html = render_template(
        "update_cate_trend.html",
        months_cate_trend=json.dumps(months_cate_trend),
        sales_cate_trend=json.dumps(sales_cate_trend)
    )
    return jsonify('', html)
```

And here is the new chart that I want to replace the original one

```
<div id="cate-trend">
    <canvas id="product-popularity-trend"></canvas>
    <script>
    let months_cate_trend_data = JSON.parse({{ months_cate_trend | tojson}});
    let sales_cate_trend_data = JSON.parse({{ sales_cate_trend | tojson }});
    console.log("hit")

    new Chart(document.getElementById("product-popularity-trend"), {
        type : 'line',
        data: {
          labels: months_cate_trend_data,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Category Sales",
              data: sales_cate_trend_data
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'chart title'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        drawOnChartArea: false,
                        drawBorder: false,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        drawOnChartArea: false,
                        drawBorder: false,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }

    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use HTML with `{{ months_cate_trend | tojson}}` template variables with `replaceWith()`. jQuery won't invoke the Flask template expander.

Comment: @Barmar I just removed all my JS from the new html, but the webpage still not responding. Nothing happens after I clicked submit.

Comment: If you remove the JS, you're just displaying an empty canvas when the AJAX returns. But I can't see anytihng that would cause the page to become unresponsive.

Comment: @Barmar After I remove the JS, and I clicked submit, the original chart (before submission) is still there, nothing happens...

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Does the Network tab show that you're receiving a response from the controller?

Comment: @Barmar no error shows, just showing the log message "hit here" from the code ```console.log("hit here")```.

Comment: And what about the Network tab? Does it show the AJAX request being sent and the response being received?

Comment: @Barmar the function in flask gets hit and the two ```print()``` statement prints the correct input. Is there a problem with my ```renter_template()``` or ```jsonify()``` ?

Comment: I don't know Flask. I'm not sure why you're rendering a template and also returning JSON. Either the client expects JSON or HTML, not both.

Comment: @Barmar I just tried to either return a html or a json, but the page is still not responding...  is the ```successs``` callback seem right?

Comment: Do you see the response in the Network tab? How many times do I have to ask the same question?

Comment: @Barmar sorry about it, there is one POST request with status 200, the payload and url seems to be correct...

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the jQuery success function.